# Need to create object of google DriveService from picasa_consumer_key, picasa_consumer_secret, authtoken, authsecret

Tags: google-drive-api

I had one winform application which used to upload photos to picasa. I had used oAuth authentication and user grants permission for the following

Picasa Web Albums
Profile Information

I store authentication token for later use. This works perfectly.

Now I want to extend it to include GOOGLE DRIVE also, so what I have done is I have added scope to Authentication as below

By file Drive API

So now user grants Permission for all three, i.e. Picasa, Profile info and Google Drive.

But I am not able to upload photos to google drive, reason being I dont know how to create object of Google Drive Service.

for Picasa I used code as below

```
OAuthParameters parameters = new OAuthParameters()
     {
        ConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY,
        ConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
        Token = AuthToken,
        TokenSecret = AuthSecret
     };

requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("XXXX", "XXXX", parameters);
service = new PicasaService(requestFactory.ApplicationName);
```

Is there anything similar for google drive?
I need to create object DriveService(auth) ..

In short I need to know how can I create OBJECT of DRIVESERVICE from four information which I have i.e. CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, AuthToken, AuthSecret.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Google Drive SDK documentation for instructions on how to retrieve and use OAuth 2.0 credentials to instantiate a service object:

https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Please note that the Drive API is supported by the Google APIs Client Library for .NET:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

Comment: thanks for the reply, i had gone through those links and I really dont want to authorize and do other stuffs again (as i have said I have the token, secret, etc). Was looking for CODE so that I can use it directly (i just need to instantiate CREDENTIAL object using token, etc..but don't know how to do that.
Any help on that will be great..thanks.